# py to exe error. (FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist.)

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe, mediapipe

so i'm working on a project that detect the hands move and use it to control the computer mouse , every thing went so good but now i need to convert it to **exe** file.
when i run my code in the pysharm or in the CMD console its working so good but when i convert i to exe file i cant open it and it keeps showing me some errors that i could not solve or find any solution online , i  will be so greatfull for help cuz i really need it ( this code is not mine i took it online and modified it a little )

Sistem information :
python 3.7.8
pyinstaller 4.8
mediapipe 0.8.9.1
autopy 4.0.0
opencv 4.5.5.62
numpy 1.21.5
windows 10

My firts code:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import math


class HandDetector:
    def __init__(self,
                 mode=False,
                 max_num_hands=1,
                 complexity=1,
                 detection=0.5,
                 track=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = max_num_hands
        self.complexity = complexity
        self.detectionCon = detection
        self.trackCon = track
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode,
                                        self.maxHands,
                                        self.complexity,
                                        self.detectionCon,
                                        self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.tipIds = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        xlist = []
        ylist = []
        bbox = []
        self.lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                xlist.append(cx)
                ylist.append(cy)
                self.lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

            xmin, xmax = min(xlist), max(xlist)
            ymin, ymax = min(ylist), max(ylist)
            bbox = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

            if draw:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (xmin - 20, ymin - 20), (xmax + 20, ymax + 20),
                              (0, 255, 0), 2)

        return self.lmList, bbox

    def fingersUp(self):
        fingers = []

        # Thumb
        if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)

        # Fingers
        for id in range(1, 5):

            if self.lmList[self.tipIds[id]][2] < self.lmList[self.tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)

        return fingers

    def findDistance(self, p1, p2, img, draw=True, r=15, t=3):
        x1, y1 = self.lmList[p1][1:]
        x2, y2 = self.lmList[p2][1:]
        cx, cy = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2

        if draw:
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), t)
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), r, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), r, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        length = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

        return length, img, [x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy]


def main():
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    detector = HandDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cam.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmlist, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmlist) != 0:
            print(lmlist[4])

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the second code :

```
import cv2
import first as htm
import numpy as np
import autopy
import mouse

wCam, hCam = 640, 480
frameR = 90
smoothening = 7
plocX, plocY = 0, 0
clocX, clocY = 0, 0

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cam.set(3, wCam)
cam.set(4, hCam)
detector = htm.HandDetector(max_num_hands=1)
wScr, hScr = autopy.screen.size()


while True:

    # 1. Find hand Landmarks
    success, img = cam.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)

    # 2. Get the tip of the index and thump
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        x1, y1 = lmList[8][1:]
        x2, y2 = lmList[4][1:]

        # 3. Check which fingers are up
        fingers = detector.fingersUp()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (frameR, frameR), (wCam - frameR, 250),
                      (255, 0, 255), 2)

        # 4. Only Index Finger : Moving Mode
        if fingers[1] == 1:

            # 5. Convert Coordinates
            x3 = np.interp(x1, (frameR, wCam - frameR), (0, wScr))
            y3 = np.interp(y1, (frameR, 250), (0, hScr))

            # 6. Smoothen Values
            clocX = plocX + (x3 - plocX) / smoothening
            clocY = plocY + (y3 - plocY) / smoothening

            # 7. Move Mouse
            autopy.mouse.move(wScr - clocX, clocY)
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            plocX, plocY = clocX, clocY

            # 8. Find distance between fingers
            length, img, lineInfo = detector.findDistance(4, 8, img)
            length_2, img, lineInfo_2 = detector.findDistance(8, 20, img)

            # 9. Click mouse if distance long / Short
            if length > 125:
                cv2.circle(img, (lineInfo[4], lineInfo[5]),
                           15, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                mouse.click('left')
            if length_2 < 115:
                mouse.click('right')

    # 10. Display
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Second.py", line 16, in <module>
    detector = htm.HandDetector(max_num_hands=1)
  File "first.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.trackCon)
  File "mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 129, in __init__
  File "mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 238, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it [this way](https://python.tutorialink.com/issues-compiling-mediapipe-with-pyinstaller-on-macos/) on windows10.

sample `*.spec`:

```
block_cipher = None

def get_mediapipe_path():
    import mediapipe
    mediapipe_path = mediapipe.__path__[0]
    return mediapipe_path


pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

mediapipe_tree = Tree(get_mediapipe_path(), prefix='mediapipe', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += mediapipe_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'mediapipe' not in x[0], a.binaries)
```

Answer (score 0):

1st the spec file is created and than according to this the application is buit.
So you 1st run the command :
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

This will buid the application file (not in working condition) and a spec file. Delete everything except the spec file and do changes  in spec file according to https://python.tutorialink.com/issues-compiling-mediapipe-with-pyinstaller-on-macos/
.
Now we will build the application file according to this updated spec file using command : `pyinstaller main.spec`
(main is the name of the spec file). Now a working exe file is built.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the path to where your `mediapipe` library is being installed. For me the path was:

```
/home/arrafi/squat-counting-application/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe
```

Then use the --add-data argument with the *mediapipe-installed-path*  while calling `pyinstaller` module to add the path manually, and then it built correctly:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "/home/arrafi/squat-counting-application/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe:mediapipe/" --icon icon.ico app.py
```

So, for you, it will be:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "your_mediapipe_installed_path:mediapipe/" --icon icon.ico app.py
```

Now, `pyinstaller` will find the path correctly and you can use the similar method for any other library facing the same issue.