# script using mediapipe breaks after making it executable with pyinstaller - FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mediapipe

I made a desktop-application using `PyQT5` library. The main library that I am using is `opencv-python-headless`, `mediapipe` and `pyserial`. So, my python script does exactly what it should do and works perfectly. But after I make it executable with `pyinstaller` it breaks. Mainly the `mediapipe` library throws this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3 (getReady_screen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "app.py", line 344, in getReady_screen
  File "app.py", line 193, in detect_squat
  File "mediapipe/python/solutions/pose.py", line 146, in __init__
  File "mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 271, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist.
```

I tried to make my script executable with this two commands, both of them throws the same error:

```
pyinstaller --onedir app.py
```

```
pyinstaller --onefile app.py
```

This is the user-name and path to my directory `squat@squat-OptiPlex-3050:~/squat-counting-application$`

These are the contents in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
absl-py==2.0.0
attrs==23.1.0
cffi==1.16.0
contourpy==1.1.1
cycler==0.12.1
docopt==0.6.2
flatbuffers==23.5.26
fonttools==4.46.0
importlib-resources==6.1.1
kiwisolver==1.4.5
matplotlib==3.7.4
mediapipe==0.10.8
num2words==0.5.13
numpy==1.24.4
opencv-python-headless==4.8.1.78
packaging==23.2
Pillow==10.1.0
protobuf==3.20.3
pycparser==2.21
pyparsing==3.1.1
PyQt5==5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.13.0
pyqtspinner==2.0.0
pyserial==3.5
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyYAML==6.0.1
six==1.16.0
sounddevice==0.4.6
zipp==3.17.0
```

###### My system specs are:

- OS Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64
- CPU Intel i5-6500T (4) @ 3.100GHz
- GPU Intel HD Graphics 530
- python 3.10.12
- pip 22.0.2

Comment: https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues?q=pyinstaller+FileNotFoundError

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804849/py-to-exe-error-filenotfounderror-the-path-does-not-exist

Comment: This other answer here, doesn't solve my issue, I tried it. I think it's something to do with OS, the other answer were solved for windows

Comment: hey, @ChristophRackwitz I found the solution for this issue with `ubuntu-22.04` or `popos-22.04`. I am posting the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked similar other solutions here, but they were for `macos` and `windows` which didn't help in my case. I am using `popos-22.04`. Here or in `ubuntu-22.04` changing the `.spec` file doesn't solve anything.

Moreover, I found out there are some dependency issues with `mediapipe==0.10.9` and `pyQt5==5.15.10` library too. Apparently, they don't support the same `opencv` package. With `pyqt5` I was facing this issue, that comes from the `opencv` dependency conflict with `mediapipe`:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/squat/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found. 
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. 

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl. 

Aborted (core dumped).
```

This dependency issue also can be solve my uninstalling all `opencv` libraries and installing `opencv-python-headless` again, but it creates issues while you want to test your application onto a new machine. You have do this manually on new system too. So, just use `pyQt6`.

##### So, here is how I solved this issue for `ubuntu-22.04` and `popos-22.04`:

- First, I removed all `pyQt5` libraries and installed `pyQt6`
- Then, I found out where `mediapipe` was being installed. For me the path was:

```
/home/arrafi/squat-counting-application/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe
```

- Then I used `--add-data` with the *mediapipe-installed-path* argument while calling `pyinstaller` module to add the path manually, and then it built correctly:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "/home/arrafi/squat-counting-application/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe:mediapipe/" --icon icon.ico app.py
```

Now, my app is building without any issue and also running correctly on other machines too.

so, here `--add-data` argument put you own path to where `mediapipe` is installed:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "your_mediapipe_installed_path:mediapipe/" --icon icon.ico app.py
```